# Lost disk space after switching to Ubuntu from Windows

Tags: boot, partitioning, disk

I am new to Ubuntu and was really excited to try it. I did my home work before installing Ubuntu on installation topics. So, I'm fairly knowledgeable about systems.

1. Hardware: Dell Inspiron 14R (N4110) came with Windows 7 pre-loaded note that my Storage Size is 750 GB.
2. I wanted to remove Windows completely (so data back-up was done to external HDD) and installed Ubuntu 14.04 LTS by following Ubuntu installation pages and specified "Replace Windows 7 with Ubuntu" while installing from boot using "Ubuntu DVD"
3. Followed all the prompts provided and installation was done.

PROBLEM: Meanwhile I was thinking that this installation will format my hard disk, remove all the Windows files, partitions and data, so that my disk space would be around 750 GB again. But, now the available disk space is 290GB something.

What happened to rest of the disk space?
How can I recover it back? If not easy, even at the cost of reinstalling Ubuntu!!

This details might help you -

["boot -info" analysis of my system](http://paste.ubuntu.com/9979437/)

gparted screen shot : in this link [here](http://s9.postimg.org/iz2je1mjz/gparted.png)

fsdk -lu report:

```
ramesh@ramesh-Dell-System-Inspiron-N4110:~$ sudo fdisk -lu
[sudo] password for ramesh: 

Disk /dev/sda: 320.1 GB, 320072933376 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 38913 cylinders, total 625142448 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x0004acbc

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048   616968191   308483072   83  Linux
/dev/sda2       616970238   625141759     4085761    5  Extended
Partition 2 does not start on physical sector boundary.
/dev/sda5       616970240   625141759     4085760   82  Linux swap / Solaris
ramesh@ramesh-Dell-System-Inspiron-N4110:~$
```

*How should I proceed?*

Comment: You're hardware specs tell us that you have a [Seagate Momentus ST320LT007](http://www.seagate.com/support/internal-hard-drives/laptop-hard-drives/momentus-thin/?sku=ST320LT007&q=ST320LT007) drive built in. This drive is 320 GB. So all appears to be as expected. How comes you had 750 GB before? Was this some compressed file system in Windows?

Comment: Thanks @Takkat actually, for raising this question. I never taught of it. But I'm not quite sure of it as I just got hold of this machine and I was told that it's 640/750GB storage unit. Now, by checking service tag on their website I got this [information](http://www.dell.com/support/home/in/en/indhs1/product-support/servicetag/728RVQ1/configuration) but not sure about the size and where to check it. In-case if you are right, i'm going to make a big fool of myself (any ideas on how could i check on ubuntu!!)

Comment: In case there was a second hard drive installed it may not have be recognized by Ubuntu, which is very unlikely. Does your BIOS show 2 hard drives? What is "MODULE, HARD DRIVE, 320, 7.2, P11, #1, TSHBA-CC" as opposed to "HARD DRIVE, 320, S2, 7.2, 2.5, 512E, 7, JUS"? Is that an additional memory card, SSD or the like?

Comment: Frankly, I don't know. I hope this might help you out `ramesh@ramesh-Dell-System-Inspiron-N4110:~$ sudo lshw -html > ~/hardwarespecs.html`. The report can be downloaded [here](http://www.datafilehost.com/d/949d2f4c)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your boot info on line 57 clearly shows that your system has an ata-ST320LT007 hard disk.  If you've bought this system as a 750GB system, there was a problem on the manufacturing line assembling your system (or you've been ripped off).

Take the machine, pack it in the original boxes and return it to the store together with the below info

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 Jan 31 22:37 ata-ST320LT007-9ZV142_W0Q07XXE -> ../../sda
```

and a copy of the hard drive specifications on the [Seagate web site](http://www.seagate.com/staticfiles/support/disc/manuals/notebook/momentus/Thin%20(.2)/100625253c.pdf) and **ask for a refund or for another machine**.

Comment: @pyDev_ram: what happened in the end?  Did you get a refund or another machine?

Comment: Dealer did replace the hard-drive...

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you missed the step to format the drive when installing.  However Takkat is correct that with the dump provided it shows only a 320gb disk with 3 partitions on it.  When you boot up do you have the option to choose ubuntu or windows 7?

Comment: No, I don't get the option of choosing. Bios directly loads Ubuntu. Is there any option to check original disk space in ubuntu or else should I go ahead and rip off my system to check the disk details ?